# How can a same Docker Layer have Different Sizes?

Tags: docker, command

I begin a download of a docker layer. There’s many layers. One of the last ones is large, weighing in at a supposed 1.9GB:

```
43b9dcd574c4: Downloading [>               ]  15.68MB/1.914GB
```

About halfway through the download, the layer fails to download and it retries 5 seconds later. This retry begins pulling in the “same layer” with the same hash. But *this time* the layer is only 830.2 MB:

```
43b9dcd574c4: Downloading [=>              ]  84.88MB/830.2MB
```

This fails as well. Docker then retries another 5 seconds later. This retry begins pulling in the “same layer” with the same hash. But *this time* the layer is only 830.**1** MB:

```
43b9dcd574c4: Downloading [==>             ]  283.9MB/830.1MB
```

Then it cycles back to the 1.9GB download attempt. What is docker doing? Is there something wrong with this layer? Other than being a terrible-practice large layer?

I get this error at the conclusion of the script:

```
docker: unexpected EOF.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 0):

It rather looks like it's reporting how much is *left* to download. So half-way through it fails, so there's another 830MB to go if it continues from same place.

Comment: Okay; so that may be - but then why is this behavior happening? And why would it circle back to the 1.9GB then?